# how to run vuejs on vagrant homestead

Tags: laravel, vue.js, redis, socket.io

I want to build a single page application with realtime features using Laravel as the backend and VueJS as the frontend, and I want to implement realtime features using Redis and socket.io.

The problem is that I'm using Windows and I cannot get Redis running on my OS.
When I'm using Laravel Homestead, I can make realtime features using VueJS that comes with Laravel along with Redis and Laravel Echo Server.
But I want to make separated VueJS frontend and Laravel backend and implement websockets using NodeJS, Redis and socket.io.

I'm wondering if I can use my Laravel Homestead Vagrant VM as a development environment to reach this goal.
I tried to serve my Vue app in Homestead and the backend in `localhost:8080` but I couldn't find a way to access it from my local machine.
In general I want a way to get a VueJS SPA with Laravel, Redis, and socket.io running on my machine or Laravel Homestead.

Comment: I would strongly recommend docker.https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

Comment: I double the comment above. With docker you are able to set up Redis in its base base configuration with one simple command. Though I'm not aware of how Vagrant works, so this comment may be a bit biased :)

Answer (score 1):

- `vagrant ssh` into Homestead
- install [Yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#debian-stable)
- (If you haven't already...do these things:)

  - `git clone` your Vue project
  - add the folders mapping to Homestead.yaml

    ```
    folders:
      - map: /path/on/your/local/computer
        to: /home/vagrant/wherever/you/cloned/it
    ```
  - `vagrant provision`
- `cd` into your Vue project
- `yarn install`
- `yarn serve --host 198.168.10.10`